# Page navigation not happening in Power bi embedded report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-3, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Two days back page navigation working fine, But suddenly Page navigation not happening in embedded report.

when i navigate "Datapackage Summary" to "Subscription Details" page not loading, but "Subscription Details" button(or link) got highlated as shown in below capture.

[image: sample image]

and also checked in network tab of IE browser shown below error..Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized

Error is:-

```
Request URL: https://df-msit-scus.analysis.windows.net/explore/explorations/1528262/cache
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized
Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.5
ActivityId: 0e8c0b1d-92e9-4ceb-b7e4-9f58b1b99350
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..........................
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 28330
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: df-msit-scus.analysis.windows.net
Origin: https://msit.powerbi.com
Referer: https://msit.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
RequestId: d8021d51-7e12-4823-117c-f69004614707
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://msit.powerbi.com
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 03 May 2017 11:24:40 GMT
RequestId: d8021d51-7e12-4823-117c-f69004614707
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
```

Please help, If you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved when i used

Origin: https://app.powerbi.com

instaed of

Origin: https://msit.powerbi.com

Needs to code as below

```
var embedUrl = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=" + reportObj.ReportID
var config = {
type: 'report',
accessToken: accessToken,
embedUrl: embedUrl,
id: reportObj.ReportID,
settings: {
filterPaneEnabled: false,
navContentPaneEnabled: true
}
};
```

===============================

Out put is :

```
Request URL: https://df-msit-scus-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/reports/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx...
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 / OK
- Request Headers
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: activityid, requestid, authorization, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: df-msit-scus-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Origin: https://app.powerbi.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

- Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: activityid,requestid,authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.powerbi.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 300
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 08 May 2017 10:06:37 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```